# Wordpress float menu links to left and right

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using the following code to generate a menu in Wordpress:

```
$defaults_topmenu = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => 'Top Menu',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults_topmenu );
```

I have to build a menu that has links aligned left and two or three links aligned to the right. How is this possible using the code from above? The menu needs to be dynamic and cannot be static.

Comment: You can split the menu into 2 menus, topmenu_left and top_menu_right :)

Comment: Hmm I see. So I would just create two menus and call them using `wp_nav_menu()` ?

Comment: Yes, and you don't need the whole code, simply add it like this <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Top Left Nav', 'container_class' => 'menu-header-left', )); ?> and <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Top Right Nav', 'container_class' => 'menu-header-right' )); ?> and then style them with css :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps:

1. `Dashboard` > `Appearance` > `Menus`
2. Select `Screen Options`.
3. Check `CSS Classes`.
4. Select your menu.
5. In each menu item, a field `CSS Classes (optional)` appears.
6. Enter different classes for the menus (for ex: `menu-left`, `menu-right`) which you want to align left and right.
7. Save your menu.
8. Add the following to your style file.

   .menu-left a
   {
       text-align: left;
   }

   .menu-right a
   {
       text-align: right;
   }

Comment: I am very glad to here this from u. Welcome :-)